# Trying to Install AWS CLI on my Mac OS (Catalina)

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, deep-learning, macos-catalina

ERROR:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-5.1.2.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

This is the message I keep getting from my terminal... Should I upgrade my python to the most current (could someone give me suggestions on how to do that w/ Mac, do I just go to python's website lol?)

What do I do to get the AWS CLI package installed? I'm trying to learn AWS to up myself and further my career

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to [install homebrew (aka brew) on Mac](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/), as a general-purpose software package manager, and then you can `brew install awscli`.

As a general rule, I think you should also leave the default Mac Python alone (especially at v2.x) and go ahead and [install the latest Python v3.x](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#targetText=Use%20Python%203%20as%20the,usr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2F.). Again, you can use brew to do this.

Comment: Pretty much follow the first link's guide?

Comment: Well, read the 2 guides and decide what makes most sense to you. I’d install brew then use brew to install awscli and ultimately Python 3, assuming that you need Python.